# How to create multiple global variables using a for loop outside of a function?

Tags: c

I have a list and I want to create a global counter for each item in the list, with the initial value set to `1`. I thought I would do this with a `for` loop (my actual list is a lot bigger than the example below) however I just realized `for` loops don't work outside of a function. How can I get the below code to work?

```
char* list[] = {"A", "B", "C"};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list); i++){
    int counter[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Global variables are initialized to 0. All you need to do is declare your variable.

Comment: the list is inside the function?

Comment: Sorry, I used 0 as a bad example. I've changed it to 1.

Comment: Then you need to put the loop inside a function, e.g. at the top of `main`, or in a separate function that's called at the top of `main`. The declaration can still go outside: `int counter[sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0])];`

Comment: Please show examples of how you intend to use the counters. You are going to implement many pieces of code, each of which use one of the counters differently? `counter[A]++`? `counterB++`? `counter['A']++`? `C++`? `x='D'; counter[x]++`?

Comment: Please explain more about `list`, the array of strings, and its meaning for your purpose? How is the list of words related to what you intend to do?

Comment: Do you want those many global counters to be initialised with equally many explicit initialiation values? Or do you want to initialise all of them programatically, all of them with the same init value?

Comment: Can you comapre what you want to achieve to constructs from other programming languages? E.g. "map", perls "hash"... ?

Comment: Is the list of strings going to be as systematically predictable as in your example? E.g. will the next be "D"? Or could there be "Z", "M", "Peter", "John Skeet", "*+-&"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this what you are after?

```
char* list[] = {"A", "B", "C"};
int counter[] = {1, 1, 1};
```

Just declare them both globally and initialize `counter` just like you initialize `list`.

It is also possible to declare `counter` globally and then initialize it in `main()` or wherever with a `for` loop:

```
char* list[] = {"A", "B", "C"};
int counter[3];

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list) / sizeof(*list); i++) {
        counter[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

or even better, figure out how much memory you need for `counter` based on the size of `list`:

```
char* list[] = {"A", "B", "C"};
int *counter;

int main(void) {
    int numElements = sizeof(list) / sizeof(*list);

    counter = malloc(numElements * sizeof(*counter));
    // check for malloc() failure

    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        counter[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Notice that you can't simply use `sizeof(list)`...that will return how much memory `list` has allocated.  You need to divide `sizeof(list)` by the size of each element, `sizeof(*list)`, to get the number of elements

Comment: `sizeof(list)/sizeof(*list)` is a constant expression and can be used as size for `counter` as `int counter[sizeof(list)/sizeof(*list)];`

Answer (score 3):

C has no facility to run such initialization code outside of functions. And since initializers to static variables at file scope need to be constant expressions, you have two options:

1. Create a script in your scripting language of choice that generates an initializer macro of the right size, for you to use as an initializer to the array. For instance, the script can read this file:

   ```
   #include "my_init_list.h"
   char* list[] = {"A", "B", "C", /* However many more */};
   int counter[] = COUNTERS_INITIALIZER;
   ```

   It would parse the initializer for `list`, and output the file `my_init_list.h` which would contain the macro `COUNTERS_INITIALIZER` that is expanded to `{1, 1, ..., 1}`. If you run the script as a step in your build process, that should do it.
2. Put the initialization code into a function, and rig your function to run once early in your program's startup code (what `main` executes when it starts running).